# Remove hardcoded template filenames in Django views

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

Basically, a `Django` view looks like this:

```
def myview(request):
    # stuff...
    return render(request, 'myfile.html', locals())
```

'myfile.html' was written to only 1 place in my Django Project, until I add tests on it:

```
def test_myview(self):
    # stuff...
    self.assertTemplateUsed(resp, 'myfile.html')
```

This is not DRY anymore. What is a good solution to this problem?
Do I need to create a file with a TEMPLATE_NAMES named tuple and import it in both views.py and tests.py?

Comment: Why what is going to change if you specify a TEMPLATE_NAMES, apart from a centrally stored place to keep your templates, you will still need to clarify which template to use, it is not a DRY problem, since this is actually a function/method/class argument, even if it repeats itself.

Comment: If the TEMPLATE_NAMES list contains all my template names, this is DRY because they are written one time, not N. Then if I decide to change the filename, I have only 1 string to edit in a well-known place, not N times browsing my whole code.

Comment: They are contained centrally but you still need to define which template to use, this is just minor to deal with as DRY, you would consider DRY for functions repeating the same logic with only small alterations. Apart from that usually templates are used spatially since most of the times views use their own templates. Finally keeping template names defined in the place they are rendered helps with readability / debugging especially when there are other people involved with the project.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand. So I guess this is not a real problem if I write it again in my tests...

Comment: Of course it's no problem, I believe it also makes it more readable for you as well, since you know with which template you are dealing if there is a problem (the other way around, centralized template names,  would suggest finding which template gets injected, that would require more work in a large project).